# Spring Data store an object and then use a query to find it in the test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, h2, spring-test

I have a very simple test using H2 and `@DataJpaTest`. The code works fine when running as a service.

I store an object and then use a query to find it. However, the object is never returned. For some reason it doesn't seem like the objects are actually stored in a way they can be queried, though the correct object is returned from the `repository.save(object)`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class MyObjectRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyObjectRepository myObjectRepository;

    @Test
    public void saveAndFindObject() {
        MyObject object = new MyObject
        object.setName("John");
        repository.save(object);
        MyObject returnedObject = repository.findByName("John");
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_object")
@Data
public class MyObject{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //All caps for Spring Batch reasons
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String NAME;

}
```

It's already encapsulated in a transaction so the session should be shared, but the returnedObject  remains `null`. How do I ensure I can query for objects I store specifically in unit tests?

EDIT: As @wjans implied, this works on the testsuite of a clean project. I have found no clear causes for this strange behavior but I'm working around it via a data.sql file in the top folder of my test resources, as the reading of data works normally.

Comment: Can you include some more relevant parts of your code?  I believe it won't be possible to tell what you are doing wrong based on what's posted here.

Comment: @wjans are you suggesting this should work as is?

Comment: What I am saying is that I think the problem lies in parts of your code not included here.  Like your repository and/or entity.

Comment: I've recreated the same code in a clean project and there it worked. I have been unable to find the cause in the project I'm currently maintaining, but I've had more strange problems since it works with a DB2 database.

Comment: @G_V Can you show you more part of your code which is the MyObject class